# Shell script to test proxy

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, rhel

I installed an HTTPIE tool on my Linux server to test our proxy for response from sites like google.com and i'm trying to write a script to test if our traffic getting through the proxy or not 
For example: I want the script to run the command below and if i get the results including the 200 OK then traffic went through fine and if i don't get response then i want the script to send an email to let me know the command did not return results.

Below is the example and then the first part of the script i wrote

```
# http --proxy=http:http://my_proxy:3128 head www.google.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4622
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2018 01:40:13 GMT
Expires: -1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Server: gws
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2018-04-28-01; expires=Mon, 28-May-2018 01:40:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=129=eWFNZlP7mCtJ_zVH7sa6kxTOc9ebMpwLMgUSVnfMA1_bJM2UFfZwly9-BqDSPFI2EaY45t7GhTAte-w783Od3JZ5MGcqmjxT86h8yKdAK1t1qlCm9oexkaYRFgRp64MK; expires=Sun, 28-Oct-2018 01:40:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Via: 1.1 isdsecwsandc2.tch.harvard.edu:3128 (Cisco-WSA/10.5.2-042)
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

So i just want to write a script to run the command above against each proxy IP address and if i get 200 OK back then go to the next one and if it times out then send me an email to let me know

The script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

proxy_targets="http://10.5.5.5:3128  http://10.5.5.6:3128 http://10.5.5.7:3128"

failed_hosts=""

for i in $proxy_targets
do
        http --proxy=http:$i head www.google.com > /dev/null
```

Comment: `man curl` and `man wget` - both have multiple proxy options (how to auth, etc) and which you'll need depends exactly on your setup.

Comment: I just want to write a script that would run the command against each proxy IP and if i get 200 OK back then go to the next one and if it times out, then send me an email

Comment: `wget` can be redirected to `/dev/null` for all output, then check the exit status with `$?` being equal to 0 then there are no errors.  I don't have a proxy to test against.

Comment: Have you try to export `http_proxy` (`export http_proxy=10.5.5.5:3128`) variable and test with `wget`?

Comment: Any help folks completing the script i started already or even providing a different script to do it?